How to integrate UI application covered by API gateway with AWS Cognito?
I have React-Js UI app , which has beck-end Spring Boot microservices under the hood. UI app and microservices hosted on ECS.
The UI app is accessible through the API Gateway.
I want to protect API Gateway with AWS Cognito.
I have already created my test user pool , launched Cognito hosted UI and etc.
Everything works fine , my gateway is protected, now it only can be accessibble with token.
But I want to implement the full user flow.
What I mean -
When user tries to enter to the UI (home page e.g.), he/she will be redirected to Cognito login page and asked to enter their creds.
After authorization is completed , user provided with the token , and can use the application , till it will be expired.
Unfortunatelly , such flow does not work OOTB. And as far as I understand requires additional effort .
Could please someone advice me , the best way how to integrate with AWS Cognito in that way?
Not just receiving token and manually addining it to postman and make calls.
One of my assumptions , is to implement Lambda function , which will work as filter.
It will check if the token is present or valid.If token is not present/expired ...  then
redirect users to hosted UI login form.
In case if token is valid , just pass it through.
But I don't know , how to store token on user side , In order to make user be able walk through the application with browser.
